# How to create relationships with many fact tables in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, relationship, powerquery, data-modeling, star-schema

[image: 1]

How do I create a relationship between these 4 fact tables and 2 dim tables? How do I slice them based on quarter of the year? How to insert Q1 2023 into the fact tables?

When I change from Q1 to Q2 on the slicer, the count of MemberID doesn't change accordingly. Why is that? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I can't see your tiny picture but obvioulsy the slicer won't do anything until you have relationships set up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape your data in Power Query. Append your 4 tables so you have a single fact table. You can also remove MemberName from your fact table as it is already in your dimension table so just retain MemberID in your fact.